# scrapy InitSpider: set Rules in __init__?

Tags: rules, scrapy

I am building a recursive webspider with an optional login. I want to make most settings dynamic via a json config file.

In my `__init__` function, I am reading this file and try to populate all variables, however, this does not work with `Rules`.

```
class CrawlpySpider(InitSpider):

...

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Constructor: overwrite parent __init__ function"""

    # Call parent init
    super(CrawlpySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Get command line arg provided configuration param
    config_file = kwargs.get('config')

    # Validate configuration file parameter
    if not config_file:
        logging.error('Missing argument "-a config"')
        logging.error('Usage: scrapy crawl crawlpy -a config=/path/to/config.json')
        self.abort = True

    # Check if it is actually a file
    elif not os.path.isfile(config_file):
        logging.error('Specified config file does not exist')
        logging.error('Not found in: "' + config_file + '"')
        self.abort = True

    # All good, read config
    else:
        # Load json config
        fpointer = open(config_file)
        data = fpointer.read()
        fpointer.close()

        # convert JSON to dict
        config = json.loads(data)

        # config['rules'] is simply a string array which looks like this:
        # config['rules'] = [
        #    'password',
        #    'reset',
        #    'delete',
        #    'disable',
        #    'drop',
        #    'logout',
        # ]

        CrawlpySpider.rules = (
            Rule(
                LinkExtractor(
                    allow_domains=(self.allowed_domains),
                    unique=True,
                    deny=tuple(config['rules'])
                ),
                callback='parse',
                follow=False
            ),
        )
```

Scrapy still crawls the pages that are present in `config['rules']` and therefore also hits the `logout` page. So the specified pages are not being denied. What am I missing here?

**Update:**

I have already tried by setting `CrawlpySpider.rules = ...` as well as `self.rules = ...` inside `__init__`. Both variants do not work.

- Spider: `InitSpider`
- Rules: `LinkExtractor`
- Before crawl: Doing login prior crawling

I even try to deny that in my `parse` function

```
    # Dive deeper?
    # The nesting depth is now handled via a custom middle-ware (middlewares.py)
    #if curr_depth < self.max_depth or self.max_depth == 0:
    links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
    for link in links:
        for ignore in self.ignores:
            if  (ignore not in link.url) and (ignore.lower() not in link.url.lower()) and link.url.find(ignore) == -1:
                yield Request(link.url, meta={'depth': curr_depth+1, 'referer': response.url})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a class attribute where you want to set an instance attribute:

```
# this:
CrawlpySpider.rules = (
# should be this:
self.rules = (
<...>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well and it did not work. I have added that information to my question.

Comment: InitSpider does not seem to have something like `_compile_rules` (as does CrawlSpider). Apparently it looks like InitSpider does not even have rules as it only inherits from Spider. CrawlSpider does implement all this.